# moving a check box in html list and moving it

Tags: html, css, menu

Really simple guys: making a collapsible list in html and css and trying to move the checkbox that controls the drop down to the FRONT of the text, as well as get rid of the dot to list the items. Right now the checkbox is placed at the end of the text. I tried to simply switch the order of the html but that screws up the drop down action.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gyetxsLu/

HTML:

```
<div class="CHECKBOXMENU">
<ul class="collapsibleList">
 <li>
  <label for="mylist-node1">Click to open list 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node1" />
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label for="mylist-node2">Click to open list 2 with subfolders</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node2" />
  <ul>
   <li>
  <label for="mylist-node3">Click to expand</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node3" />
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.collapsibleList li > input + * {
 display: none;
}

.collapsibleList li > input:checked + * {
 display: block;
}

.collapsibleList label {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: having answered your question earlier [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694714/problems-implementing-css-on-website ] I think you need a better way of hiding your lists - this is the same problem, but this time it's your edit, rather than WP's functionality that is breaking the css by adding an intermediate element - it might be wise to look for a different mechanism for showing and hiding your lists as the css is quite brittle - for example, what happens if you (or a colleague) come back in a few weeks and add a new element which is required, you'll have the same headache all over again!

Answer (score 1):

No need to restructure the HTML. `float: left` the required checkboxes and remove the bullets using `list-style-type: none`

```css
ul.collapsibleList,
ul.collapsibleList ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#mylist-node1,
#mylist-node2,
#mylist-node3 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/jxgdgLq3/4)